# Cultural Center

Tags: knowledge, pattern, connections-puzzle

> Samoan number
> Egyptian gas
> Filipino actor
> Czech sauce

What do the above items have in common? And can you find another member of this set?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the following pattern.

> Drop the first and last letters from the names of the capitals then ...
>  Samoa = A **pi** a = number
>  Egypt = C **air** o = gas
>  Philippines = M **anil** a = actor (Anil Kapoor)
>  Czech = P **ragu** e = sauce

Some other examples are:

> Albanian country (T **iran** a)
>  Greek adverb (A **then** s)
>  Senegalese abbreviation (D **aka** r)

Also, the title is related to the pattern. (thanks to a hint from OP)

> "Cultural center" suggests capital cities. Also "center" asks focusing on the middle of the words.

Comment: You got it! Bonus if you can explain how the title relates to the pattern (but I'll still accept this answer in a bit)

Comment: Wow I didn't think about the title. Added to the answer. Anyway thanks for the exciting puzzle!